# Opening document error noAccessSignal

Tags: exception, xpages, acl, lotus-domino

I'm opening a document on xPageA then from there, (pushing a button) I open the same document in xPageB to do some stuff on it.
 Sometimes on some documents, opening xpageB from xPageA results in opening xPageA with another document and throwing the follo exception.

The strange is that trying after it works... but nothing changed on the document in the meanwhile

Any ideas? The stacktrace is not so usefull no specific message.

Regards

```
    09/05/13 11.25: Exception Thrown
com.ibm.xsp.acl.NoAccessSignal
    at com.ibm.xsp.acl.NoAccessSignal.<init>(NoAccessSignal.java:35)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NotesContext.checkAccess(NotesContext.java:1551)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NotesContext.serverProcessSignedResource(NotesContext.java:975)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NotesContext.setSignerSessionRights(NotesContext.java:946)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.ModuleClassLoader$DynamicClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:619)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:171)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:619)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.Application.loadClass(Application.java:708)
    at com.ibm.xsp.library.ApplicationFacesClassLoader.loadClass(ApplicationFacesClassLoader.java:54)
    at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledPageDriver.getClassForPageName(CompiledPageDriver.java:166)
    at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledPageDriver.loadPage(CompiledPageDriver.java:61)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._createViewRoot(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:489)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.createViewRoot(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:557)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.doCreateView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:141)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerEx.createView(ViewHandlerEx.java:90)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:238)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:204)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:583)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1281)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:854)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:803)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:572)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1265)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:658)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:481)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:341)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:297)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
```

Comment: According to stacktrace check who signed design, it seems not to be related to document's RN/AN.

Comment: All the design documents are signed by the same user so shouldn't be this

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a ACL problem, be shure that you dont open the page as Anonymous or check your users ACLLevel, there is a similar problem only with a mobile site:

[NoAccessSignal Exception thrown when trying to "Load More" in Mobile Controls view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547001/noaccesssignal-exception-thrown-when-trying-to-load-more-in-mobile-controls-vi)

Also be careful if you use pageACL sometimes it results in this error.

**Update:**

add this code to your page and check the output:

```
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" value="#{javascript:return session.getEffectiveUserName();}"></xp:text>
<xp:br></xp:br>
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField2" value="#{javascript:return session.getUserName();}"></xp:text>
```

you should get the two different outputs: the first line should display the user you are logged in with, and the other the server. Check if both have enough rights.

Comment: I don't use pageACL.I get the same error from regular browser as mobile browser. And How can I check if I'm anonymous?

Comment: I don't know if the exception is thrown when I click on the button to change the page or after when is opening the new Xpage with the doc id. Where is any way to catch NOAccessSignal exception from the xpage?

Comment: hmmm... maby try some debuging by surounding your code in the button with some try catch.. have you checked the access of the server?

Comment: For the button I just added a new action to the server side actions tha open an xpage with the currentDocument.getNoteID(). What do you mean with checking access on the server?