# NoAccessSignal in XPage

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

i have seen sometimes these exceptions, but i have no clue, what a where to search. 
I know that this has to be something with ACL.

Could it be, if the session is expired and someone is trying to access some documents / modules of XPages?

What is exactly that NotesContext?

Thanx,

```
com.ibm.xsp.acl.NoAccessSignal
  at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NotesContext.checkAccess(NotesContext.java:1631)
  at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NotesContext.serverProcessSignedResource(NotesContext.java:975)
  at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NotesContext.setSignerSessionRights(NotesContext.java:946)
  at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.ModuleClassLoader$DynamicClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:349)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:626)
  at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:171)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:626)
  at com.ibm.designer.runtime.Application.loadClass(Application.java:708)
  at com.ibm.xsp.library.ApplicationFacesClassLoader.loadClass(ApplicationFacesClassLoader.java:54)
  at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledPageDriver.getClassForPageName(CompiledPageDriver.java:169)
  at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledPageDriver.loadPage(CompiledPageDriver.java:61)
  at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._createViewRoot(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:489)
  at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.createViewRoot(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:557)
  at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.doCreateView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:141)
  at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerEx.createView(ViewHandlerEx.java:90)
  at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:238)
  at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:204)
  at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
  at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
  at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
  at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:583)
  at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1281)
  at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:860)
  at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:803)
  at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:572)
  at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1265)
  at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:658)
  at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:481)
  at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:341)
  at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:297)
  at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
```

Comment: I confused with RedirectSignal, so deleted my answer. Did you check this response? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547001/noaccesssignal-exception-thrown-when-trying-to-load-more-in-mobile-controls-vi

Comment: Hi yep, but i dont have any pageACL. I have tried to find any answer, but no luck with it.

Comment: Are you storing the facescontext anywhere? perhaps as a property of a bean in viewscope?

Comment: Do you have users with "No Access" but "Read public documents" set? Mastering XPages Second Edition tells something about it on pages 1065/1066.

Comment: No, no such users with with public documents allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple said: in this case NotesContext handles security (signatures, ACL, RN/AN, ...)

In your case there are few options:

1. Bad signature - code signer must be mentioned in "Sign or run unrestricted methods and operations" of server document.
2. URL with `documentid=` param pointing to document user has no read access to
3. Very common mistake - "Maximum web access" in ACL too low.